# How do I split a string in Rust?

Tags: rust

From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), it's not clear. In Java you could use the `split` method like so:

```java
"some string 123 ffd".split("123");
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html

Comment: @bow Is there a way to make it a String array instead of a vector?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that, directly at least. You'd probably have to manually iterate over the `Split` and set it into the array. Of course this means the number of items in each split must be the same since arrays are fixed size and you have to have the array defined before. I imagine this may be more trouble than simply creating a `Vec`.

Answer (score 428, accepted):

Use [`split()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split)

```
let parts = "some string 123 content".split("123");
```

This gives an iterator, which you can loop over, or `collect()` into a vector. For example:

```
for part in parts {
    println!("{}", part)
}
```

Or:

```
let collection = parts.collect::<Vec<&str>>();
dbg!(collection);
```

Or:

```
let collection: Vec<&str> = parts.collect();
dbg!(collection);
```

Comment: You can also write it `.collect::<Vec<_>>()`.

Comment: how do I get the length of the result - `let split`? `split.len()` doesn't exist.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Use `.count()`. `len()` is only for iterators which know their exact size without needing to be consumed, `count()` consumes the iterator.

Comment: `error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `split` as mutable`

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp `let mut split`, sorry.

Comment: In Rust 1.0, `split_str()` doesn't exist, but `"hi\nthere".split("\n")` works

Comment: @Manishearth how about splitting into characters? Like "foo" -> ['f','o','o']?

Comment: @Manishearth thank you... I LITERALLY started Rust today, coming into it as a Rubyist.

Comment: @Manishearth thanks for answering, in the example you wrote you collected a Vec<&str> , what should I do to collect a Vec<String>

Answer (score 207):

There are three simple ways:

1. By **[separator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split)**:

   ```
    s.split("separator")  |  s.split('/')  |  s.split(char::is_numeric)
   ```
2. By **[whitespace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace)**:

   ```
    s.split_whitespace()
   ```
3. By **[newlines](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines)**:

   ```
    s.lines()
   ```
4. By **[regex](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.2/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.split)**: *(using `regex` crate)*

   ```
    Regex::new(r"\s").unwrap().split("one two three")
   ```

The result of each kind is an iterator:

```
let text = "foo\r\nbar\n\nbaz\n";
let mut lines = text.lines();

assert_eq!(Some("foo"), lines.next());
assert_eq!(Some("bar"), lines.next());
assert_eq!(Some(""), lines.next());
assert_eq!(Some("baz"), lines.next());

assert_eq!(None, lines.next());
```

Answer (score 61):

There is a special method [`split` for struct `String`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split):

```
fn split<'a, P>(&'a self, pat: P) -> Split<'a, P> where P: Pattern<'a>
```

Split by word:

```
let v: Vec<&str> = "Mary had a little lamb".split(' ').collect();
assert_eq!(v, ["Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb"]);
```

Split by delimiter:

```
let v: Vec<&str> = "lion::tiger::leopard".split("::").collect();
assert_eq!(v, ["lion", "tiger", "leopard"]);
```

Split by closure:

```
let v: Vec<&str> = "abc1def2ghi".split(|c: char| c.is_numeric()).collect();
assert_eq!(v, ["abc", "def", "ghi"]);
```

Answer (score 41):

`split` returns an [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html), which you can convert into a `Vec` using [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect): `split_line.collect::<Vec<_>>()`. Going through an iterator instead of returning a `Vec` directly has several advantages:

- `split` is lazy. This means that it won't really split the line until you need it. That way it won't waste time splitting the whole string if you only need the first few values: `split_line.take(2).collect::<Vec<_>>()`, or even if you need only the first value that can be converted to an integer: `split_line.filter_map(|x| x.parse::<i32>().ok()).next()`. This last example won't waste time attempting to process the "23.0" but will stop processing immediately once it finds the "1".
- `split` makes no assumption on the way you want to store the result. You can use a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), but you can also use anything that implements [`FromIterator<&str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html), for example a [`LinkedList`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html) or a [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html), or any custom type that implements `FromIterator<&str>`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, any ideas why `let x = line.unwrap().split(",").collect::<Vec<_>>();` does not work unless it is separated into two separate lines: `let x = line.unwrap();` and `let x = x.split(",").collect::<Vec<_>>();`? The error message says: `temporary value created here  ^ temporary value dropped here while still borrowed`

Comment: However it works as expected if I use `let x = line.as_ref().unwrap().split(",").collect::<Vec<_>>();`

Answer (score 15):

There's also [`split_whitespace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace)

```
fn main() {
    let words: Vec<&str> = "   foo   bar\t\nbaz   ".split_whitespace().collect();
    println!("{:?}", words);
    // ["foo", "bar", "baz"] 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for the Python-flavoured split where you tuple-unpack the two ends of the split string, you can do

```rust
if let Some((a, b)) = line.split_once(' ') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nice addition, related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517187/split-string-only-once-in-rust

Answer (score 3):

The OP's question was how to split with a multi-character string and here is a way to get the results of `part1` and `part2` as `String`s  instead in a `vector`.
Here splitted with the non-ASCII character string `"☄☃"` in place of `"123"`:

```
let s = "☄☃";  // also works with non-ASCII characters
let mut part1 = "some string ☄☃ ffd".to_string();
let _t;
let part2;
if let Some(idx) = part1.find(s) {
    part2 = part1.split_off(idx + s.len());
    _t = part1.split_off(idx);
}
else {
    part2 = "".to_string();
}
```

gets: `part1 = "some string "`
         `part2 = " ffd"`

If `"☄☃"` not is found `part1` contains the untouched original `String` and `part2` is empty.

---

Here is a nice example in Rosetta Code -
*Split a character string based on change of character* - of how you can turn a short solution using `split_off`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut part1 = "gHHH5YY++///\\".to_string();
    if let Some(mut last) = part1.chars().next() {
        let mut pos = 0;
        while let Some(c) = part1.chars().find(|&c| {if c != last {true} else {pos += c.len_utf8(); false}}) {
            let part2 = part1.split_off(pos);
            print!("{}, ", part1);
            part1 = part2;
            last = c;
            pos = 0;
        }
    }
    println!("{}", part1);
}
```

**into [that](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Split_a_character_string_based_on_change_of_character#Rust)**

*Task*
*Split a (character) string into comma (plus a blank) delimited strings based on a change of character (left to right).*