# How to extract two integers from a string?

Tags: input, rust

How do I extract two `i32`s from a single line of input in Rust? In Python I can read two `int`s like:

```python
a, b = map(int, input().split()) #  "2 3"  =>  a=2 and b=3
```

As of Rust 1.3.0, I can run the following to read one i32:

```rust
let mut s = String::new();
std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut s).ok().expect("read_line panic");
let n: i32 = s.trim().parse().ok().expect("parse panic");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Rust?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643688/how-to-split-a-string-in-rust)

Comment: Have you tried combining `map` and `split` like the Python code? It is expected that you show *some* effort at solving your own problem, Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: By the way. As of Rust 1.4.0 (released about two weeks ago), `result.expect("msg")` is available and objectively better than `.ok().expect("msg")` (because it includes the contents of the `Err` in the panic message).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`&str` has a [`split_whitespace()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace) method which returns an iterator yielding parts of the target string separated by an arbitrary amount of whitespace, much like `split()` in Python. You can use  the [`map()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) iterator adapter to convert each part to a number:

```
let mut s = String::new();
std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut s).expect("read_line error");

let mut parts = s.split_whitespace().map(|s| s.parse::<i32>());
match (parts.next(), parts.next()) {
    (Some(Ok(a)), Some(Ok(b))) => {
        // a and b are i32
    }
    // handle other problems: not enough numbers, numbers are invalid, etc
    _ => {}  // ignore invalid input
}
```

This looks a lot more verbose than the Python version, but that's mostly because in Python all errors will be thrown as exceptions, while in Rust you have to handle them explicitly. If you don't care about them, you can throw `match` away:

```
let a = parts.next().unwrap().unwrap();
let b = parts.next().unwrap().unwrap();
```

Even another approach would be to use a handy `collect()` implementation for `Result<Vec<_>, _>`:

```
let items: Result<Vec<i32>, _> = parts.collect();
```

This way if any of numbers in the input string fail to parse, `items` will contain the corresponding `Err` value, but if they all are parsed successfully, then `items` will contain `Ok` variant with the vector of parsed numbers. With this approach you also do not need to specify `::<i32>()` in `parse()` invocation, as it will be inferred automatically (no need for `mut` either):

```
let parts = s.split_whitespace().map(|s| s.parse());
```

Also there is no one-liner function to read a string from stdin in the standard library. It is somewhat unfortunate but rarely a problem in practice. There are libraries which provide such functionality; see other answers to find some examples.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`text_io`](https://crates.io/crates/text_io) crate which offers a macro `read!` to read from standard input to produce tuples:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate text_io;
let (a, b): (i32, i32);
scan!("{} {}", a, b);
```

You can also read the values one by one

```
#[macro_use] extern crate text_io;
let a: i32 = read!();
let b: i32 = read!();
```

Answer (score 3):

The Rust code is always going to be more verbose than the Python one. But since version 1.26, Rust also supports slice patterns as shown below. The code looks more readable in my opinion.

```
fn main() {
    let a = "2 3";
    if let [Ok(aa), Ok(aaa)] = &a.split(" ")
                                 .map(|a| a.parse::<i32>())
                                 .collect::<Vec<_>>()[..] {
        println!("{:?} {:?}", aa, aaa);
    }
}
```