# Split string only once in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to split a string by a separator only once and put it into a tuple. I tried doing

```
fn splitOnce(in_string: &str) -> (&str, &str) {
    let mut splitter = in_string.split(':');
    let first = splitter.next().unwrap();
    let second = splitter.fold("".to_string(), |a, b| a + b); 
    (first, &second)
}
```

but I keep getting told that `second` does not live long enough. I guess it's saying that because `splitter` only exists inside the function block but I'm not really sure how to address that. How to I coerce `second` into existing beyond the function block? Or is there a better way to split a string only once?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are looking for [`str::splitn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.splitn):

```
fn split_once(in_string: &str) -> (&str, &str) {
    let mut splitter = in_string.splitn(2, ':');
    let first = splitter.next().unwrap();
    let second = splitter.next().unwrap();
    (first, second)
}

fn main() {
    let (a, b) = split_once("hello:world:earth");
    println!("{} --- {}", a, b)
}
```

Note that Rust uses `snake_case`.

---

> I guess it's saying that because splitter only exists inside the function block

Nope, it's because you've created a `String` and are trying to return a reference to it; [you cannot do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str). `second` is what doesn't live long enough.

> How to I coerce `second` into existing beyond the function block?

You don't. This is a fundamental aspect of Rust. If something needs to live for a certain mount of time, you *just have to make it exist for that long*. In this case, as in the linked question, you'd return the `String`:

```
fn split_once(in_string: &str) -> (&str, String) {
    let mut splitter = in_string.split(':');
    let first = splitter.next().unwrap();
    let second = splitter.fold("".to_string(), |a, b| a + b); 
    (first, second)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[`str::split_once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_once) is now built-in.

Doc examples:

```rust
assert_eq!("cfg".split_once('='), None);
assert_eq!("cfg=".split_once('='), Some(("cfg", "")));
assert_eq!("cfg=foo".split_once('='), Some(("cfg", "foo")));
assert_eq!("cfg=foo=bar".split_once('='), Some(("cfg", "foo=bar")));
```