# How to split a string in Rust with multiple parameters?

Tags: rust

I am trying to split a string in Rust using both whitespace and `,`. I tried doing

```
let v: Vec<&str> = "Mary had a little lamb".split_whitespace().collect(); 
let c: Vec<&str> = v.split(',').collect();
```

The result:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> char: std::ops::FnMut<(&'r &str,)>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:26
  |
3 |     let c: Vec<&str> = v.split(',').collect();
  |                          ^^^^^ the trait `for<'r> std::ops::FnMut<(&'r &str,)>` is not implemented for `char`

error[E0599]: no method named `collect` found for type `std::slice::Split<'_, &str, char>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:37
  |
3 |     let c: Vec<&str> = v.split(',').collect();
  |                                     ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `std::slice::Split<'_, &str, char> : std::iter::Iterator`
          `&mut std::slice::Split<'_, &str, char> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643688/how-to-split-a-string-in-rust)

Answer (score 11):

Use a closure:

```
let v: Vec<&str> = "Mary had a little lamb."
    .split(|c| c == ',' || c == ' ')
    .collect();
```

This is based upon the [String documentation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Ballow(unused)%5D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0Alet%20v%3A%20Vec%3C%26str%3E%20%3D%20%22abc1defXghi%22.split(%7Cc%7C%20c%20%3D%3D%20%271%27%20%7C%7C%20c%20%3D%3D%20%27X%27).collect()%3B%0Aassert_eq!(v%2C%20%5B%22abc%22%2C%20%22def%22%2C%20%22ghi%22%5D)%3B%0A%7D).

Answer (score 6):

Pass a slice with the `char`s to it:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "1,2 3";
    let v: Vec<_> = s.split([' ', ','].as_ref()).collect();

    assert_eq!(v, ["1", "2", "3"]);
}
```

`split` takes an argument of type `Pattern`. To see what concretely you can pass as parameter, see [the implementors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html#implementors)