# Need to extract the last word in a Rust string

Tags: string, rust, rust-cargo

I am doing some processing of a string in Rust, and I need to be able to extract the last set of characters from that string. In other words, given a string like the following:

```
some|not|necessarily|long|name
```

I need to be able to get the last part of that string, namely "name" and put it into another String or a &str, in a manner like:

```
let last = call_some_function("some|not|necessarily|long|name");
```

so that last becomes equal to "name".

Is there a way to do this? Is there a string function that will allow this to be done easily? If not (after looking at the documentation, I doubt that there is), how would one do this in Rust?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643688/how-do-i-split-a-string-in-rust)

Comment: Actually, no it doesn't. The code at the link you provided appears to actually *remove* the part I am looking for. This would cause "some|not|necessarily|long|name" to return "some|not|necessarily|long|". That is what I am seeing when I test that code.

Comment: But what happens if you split on `"|"` and take the last element returned?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While the answer from @effect is correct, it is not the most idiomatic nor the most performant way to do it. It'll walk the entire string and match all of the `|`s to reach the last. You can make it better, but there is a method of `str` that does exactly what you want - [`rsplit_once()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.rsplit_once):

```rust
let (_, name) = s.rsplit_once('|').unwrap();
// Or
// let name = s.rsplit_once('|').unwrap().1;
//
// You can also use a multichar separator:
// let (_, name) = s.rsplit_once("|").unwrap();
// But in the case of a single character, a `char` type is likely to be more performant.
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2453c40bf3a17962f4099f4ab71aac3c).

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [String::split()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split) method, which will return an iterator over the substrings split by that separator, and then use the [Iterator::last()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.last) method to return the last element in the iterator, like so:

```
let s = String::from("some|not|necessarily|long|name");
let last = s.split('|').last().unwrap();
    
assert_eq!(last, "name");
```

Please also note that string slices (`&str`) also implement the `split` method, so you don't *need* to use `std::String`.

```
let s = "some|not|necessarily|long|name";
let last = s.split('|').last().unwrap();
    
assert_eq!(last, "name");
```

Comment: This is a great solution and it works, but the solution below appears to be more efficient and, based on my testing, faster. I did give yours an up- vote because it was the first working solution to my problem.